# Number and size of freehub ball bearings for Shimano FH-HG50 (30H 9801)

Tags: shimano, bearings, freehub

I need help with an overhaul of the Shimano freehub that comes with the [FH-HG50 hub](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjokpzn7ef8AhXKAewKHaLoAFAQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paul-lange.de%2Fde%2Fservice%2Fdownloads%2Fexplosionszeichnungen.html%3Ffile%3Dfiles%2F01_Paul-Lange%2F07_Service%2F04_Downloads%2FShimano%2Fexplosionszeichnungen%2FFH%2FFH-HG50.pdf) (part no 30H 9801). How many balls go into the inner and the outer race? What size should they have?

I have already disassembled the freehub and counted 48 ball bearings in total. They fell out of both races simultaneously so I cannot say how many were in either race. Some look larger than others and I am unsure what their nominal size should be.

Edit: After servicing the freehub, I can confirm the correct size and number of ball bearings is 25 1/8“ ball bearings for each race, ie 50 in total.

Comment: I misunderstood which part you have in mind. THe hub axle bearings have 18 balls, but the freehub itself has different ball bearings with different bearing balls. Do those 48 pcs include the balls in the hub itself or not?

Comment: Hi @VladimirFГероямслава I am asking about the freehub, not the hub. The 48 ball bearings are from inside the freehub and do not incl the 18 ball bearings (larger diameter) of the hub.

Comment: I was also quite confused because for me a ball bearing is the whole piece that includes the bearing balls, the cone and the cup or the races and possibly a cage.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion caused. I explicitly asked about the freehub body ball bearings and not the hub.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава that's a possible meaning, but "ball bearing" more often refers to the individual balls. The whole assembly would often be called just a "bearing" (or "cartridge bearing" etc. If appropriate)

Comment: The apparent size difference can also be caused by corrosion or contamination - perhaps related to why you need to strip it down in the first place. They are the same in both races, but in mine the balls from one race were in a much worse state than the other

Comment: @ChrisH It's probably mainly me being used to use English in scientific texts and other documents where exact terminology is important, although I am just a physicist, not an engineer. And the informal usage might be more liberal. And also that in my language such a confusion is impossible and it is quite natural for me to use the direct equivalents to my language.  I found this https://www.industrialheating.com/articles/91798-bearing-balls-not-ball-bearings

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I'd say that "ball bearing" meaning the individual balls is the stricter terminology, with the whole thing being referred to as a "(ball) bearing assembly/unit" or more likely by a more specific term like "cartridge bearing" or "cup and cone bearing".  But I've worked in engineering (not really the right sort) in the UK, and terminology is used slightly differently in different places (I'm back in Physics now)

Comment: @ChrisH That sounds very unlikely to me (that it would be the stricter terminology). At least not the official one. A ball is not a bearing at least in the sense used by the dictionary of mechanical engineering https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780199587438.001.0001/acref-9780199587438-e-468?rskey=mU9ghh&result=461 or also Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Shimano freehub bodies are not officially meant to be opened and serviced, there is no exploded views nor procedures in dealer's manuals available on the manufacturer's technical documentation website to confirm the size and the number of ball bearings.

Still, a few Internet users demonstrated that opening an Hyperglide freehub body such as yours is doable and they reported that there were 50 ball bearings (25 on each side) of size 1/8" on their particular model. I suppose 48 balls as you counted is also possible since it is very close to 50. The difference in size you seem to notice might be due to manufacturing tolerance. I suggest measuring their diameter with an electronic caliper if you have access to one.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. I assume 50 would be the correct number of ball bearings as I was able to fit 25 of the worn steel balls into the outer race and still had a bit of a gap when I tried to reassemble it the other day. I will go ahead and order 50 new 1/8“ steel balls then.

Answer (score 3):

This older model freehub body can be overhauled. The bearing size is 1/8" and a 25 count for both the inner and outer races (50 1/8" balls total).  Often times, extreme wear of a loose ball bearing system can yield what appear to be differing sized ball-bearings.  They started out life as the same diameter, but uneven wear, brinelling of the races and dirt ingress create a situation where there is uneven load so wear at any one ball can be much different than for another. I've seen bearing balls come out where the outer layers were peeling away like an onion. Other times I've seen balls that have fractured and the larger piece became rounded (albeit imperfectly) again from wear as the bearing remained in service.

[A popular YouTube bike mechanic](https://youtu.be/X9gIEG1db0s), RJ the Bike Guy, has a video discussing the overhaul of a Shimano freehub body that I link to here.  It should be helpful to get you through the process.

Comment: I've certainly counted 50 (2x25 1/8") in very similar shimano hubs. They're fiddly to service but it's quite doable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Jeff. I only accepted the other one as it came in before yours. I appreciate the added context regarding wear and how it might affect perceived size and potentially number of the steel balls. Thanks for linking the YouTube video.

Comment: @jaspb You're welcome!